# Laravel session not destorying

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have read so many stack questions but still i cant fix my issue
i have some data of array which i will store in session after successful login

```
 session(['menuList' => $menuList]);
```

and

```
 session(['pageList' => $fullPage]);
```

when user click logout button then i will do the following

```
 session_destroy();
            $request->session()->forget('pageList');
            $request->session()->forget('menuList');
            Session::flush();
            $request->session()->flush();
            Auth::logout();
```

but still if i print session value in login page session has not been destroyed. i dont know why it doesn't destroy

Even i given

```
public function __construct()
{
    session_start();
}
```

Can any one help me how i can fix this issue

Comment: Laravel does not use the native session stuff, `session_start()` and `session_destroy()` does not affect the Laravel session.

Comment: @sisve.oh okay. but i added only because session flush not worked even session forget too

Answer (score 0):

Using `$request->session()` is for current request, For all requests you need just `session()`, use as below

```
session()->forget('pageList');
```

Comment: @even i checked in incognito window

Comment: @DigitalDrifter : It will remove all data not specific

Comment: @DigitalDrifter@ C2486.finaly fixed when i add logout route outside middleware .

Comment: @vision : which  `middleware` ?

Comment: @– C2486 my logout route was in inside user authentication middleware.that is customer middleware which i added to authentatication check

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by adding Logout Route Outside the middleware user session